Unable to preview the data from the azure sql database in adf dataset

I have created the Linked Service for the Azure SQL database and while configuring the data set, I'm unable preview the tables data.
How to create the data set that contains all the database objects such as tables, schemas, views, stored procedures, etc dynamically.
Here my agenda is copying the data between the two sql server databases.

In Azure SQL dataset Tables and views, you need to select from drop down of table. To make it dynamic you need to create parameter for schema name and table name or view name and add them in table dropdown in connection of dataset

How to create all objects like tables, views, schemas, stored procedures parameters - Sorry I do not know the process. could you help me out


How to create the data set that contains all the database objects such as tables, schemas, views, stored procedures, etc dynamically.

In Azure SQL dataset to see preview of Tables or views, you need to select it from drop down list of table as you can see below:

To make it dynamic you need to create parameter for schema name and table name or view name:

and then you need to assign this parameter to table as below.

Now, pass the name of view or table and schema to the dataset properties as you see in below image. For dynamic stored procedure you need to enter it manually in source of copy activity and dataset.


How about views, schemas, users?

FOR VIEWS ANND SCHEMA IS SAME AS TABLE

https://i.imgur.com/9hHTB80.png - In Parameters, I have added 3 (table_name, Schema_name and View_name) but in the connection, it is showing only table_name and schema_name

Can you show the full pipeline in your answer please

You can pass view name in your tablename parameter.

Man, its so confusing answer you have provided, I cannot follow one step also from your given answer. Please.

please check the answer now I have edited it
